# Blogger Item/Static Page Showing No Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I have been customising a **Blogger** Blog for some weeks now and I'm getting towards the end of the job; one of the first steps I did was create the basic pages/structure of the blog; for example making an Archives page and link, Legal page and link, etc.

All pages were displaying well, even within the preliminary customisation but now that script and code has been modified more so the pages are no longer displaying any content; the banner, logo, sidebar, footer, etc are all displayed but the body content, i.e. what you type and publish online, is missing.

The only script/code that I could say relates to this issue is the modification of the Blog **Widget**; this is used to display the content of a blog post so I would assume that MAYBE this is also used to display static and item page content too.

So much has been modified that I couldn't begin to embed the 'relevant' **code** but if someone can tell me that the Blog **Widget** **Script** is where the problem will lie then I should be able to backtrack my modifications and resolve it.

This may be a long shot, I know, but any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to provide an accurate answer without looking at the code but the likely cause of this problem is related to the conditional statements - `<data:post.body/>` has likely been enclosed between `b:if` statements which only shows it on post page (via a condition like `data:blog.pageType == "item"`). Try removing these types of `b:if` conditional statements which enclose the `<data:post.body/>` tag or sharing the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through investigation I have found the solution to the issue; it was indeed the use of certain `b:if` functions that were preventing the display of my custom archive.

If you decide to run with a custom archive such as one used by [Sam Writes](http://www.sarwrites.com/2015/09/create-archive-listpage-for-blogger.html) the Blogger mainframe won't treat the page any different to a normal 'Static Page', something that seems so obvious now but not really clarified anywhere on the net clearly. So in my situation I had set my Blog Widgets to be hidden on certain pages, i.e. "Blog1" was only on my homepage and "Blog2" was on the Posts pages.

Because the Archive was set up on a Static page there was no Blog Widget set up to display items on a Static page so no content would show. The solution was to create a third Blog Widget (Blog3) that would only display on Static Pages; once set up everything was back to normal.

There may be other work arounds or simpler solutions but I basically went through the various combinations of show/hide scripting from [VRC Works](https://www.vrcworks.net/blog/how-to-hide-or-display-blogger-widgets/#display_widget_post_pages) until I had a combination that worked; hiding Blog3 on the Homepage, for example, hid it from the entire blog so I would suggest doing trial and error if anyone comes across this issue. For the sake of information and clarity too I will post an abbreviated version of my code here:

```
 <b:widget id='Blog3' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
 <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>
  <b:if cond='!data:mobile'>
    <!-- posts -->
 <!-- Ad -->
    <!-- navigation -->
    <!-- feed links -->
  <b:else/>
    <b:include name='mobile-main'/>
  </b:if>

  <b:if cond='data:top.showPlusOne'>
    <data:top.googlePlusBootstrap/>
  </b:if>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
```